# Excel: Icon and Text in same cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to combine icons and text in one cell to create a task tracking spreadsheet. Can anyone point me in the direction of some VBA to combine these. I've added a screenshot of the icons and text I want combined, the icons have been formatted to be the cell value.

[image]

I've tried using the concatenate formula and can't find any VBA online to support this - I'm not quite good enough with VBA to just know what to do.

TIA

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `the icons have been formatted to be the cell value`.

Comment: I used the 'place in cell' function, so when you select the cell it comes up with the text value of the icon in the formula bar.

Comment: It appears that the in-cell image occupies the entire cell, preventing text from being placed in the cell. It's just my guess. I haven't seen MS official document about it.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what it is, but I've seen a spreadsheet on Etsy that does it, so there's got to be something in VBA that can create a workaround? I would just purchase the Etsy spreadsheet to find out how it's done but the code is probably protected so people can't do what I'm trying to do. I just really love the concept of it.

Comment: What's the url of Etsy template?

Comment: I thought this was standard conditional formatting, but for the priority icons you can't use words to assign icons... https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/1472927920/client-tracker-management-for-small?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=spreadsheet&ref=sr_gallery-1-1&pro=1&bes=1&sts=1&dd=1&search_preloaded_img=1&organic_search_click=1

Comment: Here's an example usage  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9x-6O6FBYPE  Looks neat to me, but not yet available in my Excel version....

Comment: Does simply merging cells help?